# I start upgrade and download only part of the packages

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04

I  start upgrade  and download only 1366 packages out of 19..  How to  Restart  remaining packages for downloading ?

Comment: OMG U DOWNLOADED 1345 MORE PACKAGES THAN YOU SHOULD HAVE!

Comment: @Alvar meant `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. If after that you still see some packages not updated (it would say they are "retained"), then do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: If you are upgrading through the GUI update manager then It will resume automatically from where its terminated. all you need to do is just run normally,:)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As it stands, your question may need a little more information  in order for it to be answered. Please edit the question and add more details. For example, are you trying to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04? What messages you get (error or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade from the terminal then you can simply run it with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

thats it. It will upgrade your system to latest release . I mean to 13.04.

If the upgrade were aborted, clean the download folder first

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

hope that helps.

Comment: i try sudo do-release-upgrade they give me error msg

Comment: so you have terminated it in middle . ok do like ` sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/lock `